# Python IdentationError

Tags: python

Приходится править скрипт с домашнего ПК, через встренный редактор хостера, через редактор на смартфоне...
Иногда выскакивает эта ошибка. Исправишь в одном месте, вылезает в другом. Хоть у всего скрипта отступы переделывай.
Может быть есть у опытных питонщиков, какая-то хитрость для борьбы с этой ошибкой?

Comment: Всегда использовать только пробелы.

Comment: Конечно, только четыре пробела. Но все равно как-то умудряются появляться табы.

Comment: Если редактор делает автоотступы, то должна быть настроена автозамена табуляции на пробелы. Откуда еще табуляция сама может появиться?

Comment: в вашем случае только перейти на 1 пробел в виде отступа, будет не по стандартам, но сразу увидете когда появится табуляция. Хостер настроек обычно не продоставляет для своих редакторов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В основном авто-табуляция срабатывает если 4 пробела стоят подряд, если у вас не такие большие цепочки условий можно уменьшить оступы до одного пробела, python это поддерживает. Например вместо:

```
x = 5
y = 1
if x > y:
    y += 1
    if y < 0:
        y = 1
```

Писать

```
x = 5
y = 1
if x > y:
 y += 1
 if y < 0:
  y = 1
```

Ещё вместо пробелов можно использовать только табуляцию если она и так лезет.)

Длинные строки понижают читаемость кода, в python можно перейти на другую строку перед этим поставив знак `\` Пример:

```
x = 546
y = 234
z = 788
print(x+y+z/y*z*x+len(globals())+6*x \
+z+y+x)
```

Comment: Про один пробел - отличная идея! В вертикальной ориентации на телефоне будет больше текста влазить :) А как насчет фигурных скобок? Сильно плохо? `def my_func(): {some code}`

Comment: @Skotinin, лучше побольше строк, длинные строки только портят код, в python для переноса строки прямо в выражении можно знаком \

Comment: за счет этого можно немного увеличить шрифт и не делать строки слишком короткими.

Comment: @Skotinin, я дополнил ответ для более понятного объяснения использования знака \

Comment: @Skotinin, globals() - стандартная функция python которая возвращает словарь всех глобальных имён в программе.

Comment: @MihailRis не всех, а только в текущем пространстве имён

Comment: @andreymal, да, точно.

Answer (score 1):

Питон не интересует как вы делаете отступы, если вы делаете это одинаково во всём модуле. [Python: Myths about Indentation](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk).

Также как и в любом другом языке, вы не хотите смешивать табы и с пробелами для создания отступов—это может привести к коду, который работает не так как кажется на первый взгляд. Визуальный отступ может вводить в заблуждение, пример для С: [Apple's SSL/TLS bug (22 Feb 2014)](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html).

Можно использовать `python -tt`, чтобы автоматически проверять непоследовательное использование табов. `git` позволяет как преобразовать существующие файлы с табами, так и не допустить появление новых таких файлов (`.gitattributes`: `*.py    filter=spabs`). [Converting a Git repo from tabs to spaces](https://eev.ee/blog/2016/06/04/converting-a-git-repo-from-tabs-to-spaces/).

Про *«встренный редактор хостера»:* не используйте инструменты, которые без вашего ведома добавляют табы в код (не нужно отвёрткой гвозди забивать)—к тому же вопрос звучит так как будто вы редактируете файлы руками на живом сервере. Вместо этого, развёртывание лучше к одной команде свести. Что эта за команда: `git push` или `fab deploy` или что-то другое--не важно: на домашнем PC, для редактирования Питон-кода, вы можете использовать редактор, который вам нужен, а не хостеру.

На телефоне, поставьте аналог [Pythonista для iOS](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/).

Редактор/IDE с поддержкой Питона, наверняка поддерживает создание/удаление отступа по одной клавише (Tab и Backspace соответственно). Что он при этом в файл пишет, может зависеть от уже существующего кода в модуле (если модуль использует 2 пробела, Tab будет использовать 2 пробела, если 4, то 4). Если хотите, вы можете настроить, чтобы код переформатировался бы при сохранении в соответствии с выбранными правилами, например, согласно pep-8, используя [`yapf` утилиту или аналоги](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yapf).